# How to implement BooleanSimilarityFactory in SOLR cloud-mode

Tags: search, solr

I am using SOLR 9.1.1 for search and have next demands - document has different fields, like Title, Author, ShortSummary etc. Search should return at first documents with term or phrase in Title, newest first, then in Author, newest first, then ShortSummary, newest first etc.
I think, changing similarity to BooleanSimilarityFactory and using edismax and boosts for fields and sorting by score and then by date will solve my problem.
But I cannot figure out, how to do it.

I tried to make my own configset and added to managed-schema.xml next line
 before all fields declarations etc. I also changed name of schema inside of managed-schema.xml file. This configset was uploaded to zoo keeper and then new collection was created based on this configset.
But when I check this collection settings - I see, that _default schema was taken as base.

I've read question, where possible solution to write own similarity class, but I am not familiar with java and I did not find "How-To" tutorial for this situation.

Thanks for all answers - both what I am doing wrong and may be other strategy .

Comment: If _any_ term matches in `Title` - even it being a very, very common one compared to what matches in the other fields - should still make the hit in Title` be returned first? If you add a very large boost that scales down as the terms become less important, and disable termvectors/etc. for the field - does that work without using any other similarity?

Comment: Yes, I think ideally would be score=boost. For example, we have term "water" in 20 Titles. Boost for Title=50. Then I would get 20 results with score=50 and can also sort it by date. This is my idea. Yes, I added very large boost for Title, but I still don't know how I can sort Titles by date, then Author by date etc.

Comment: If you can use regular Lucene syntax, you can do that by doing `title:water^=50`: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html#constant-score-with - I don't think the regular dismax syntax handles it, but give it a try.